# How to flip polarity of battery with DIY device

Tags: battery-charging

Say I have a small electric motor I'm spinning with a hand crank to generate electricity and charge a battery. Every ten seconds, I slowly slow down to a stop and start spinning the other way. This will flip the direction of the current, and I will "anti charge" the battery, right?

What is the simplest way to set up a system so the electricity generated from cranking in the wrong direction is still used to charge the battery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with 4 diodes in a [diode bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_bridge) configuration.

Parts with 4 diodes in this configuration are available in a single package rather than having to build it yourself.

You will however lose two voltage drops (about 1.2V) worth of voltage. Depending on the situation you could use schottky diodes to reduce this loss at the cost of higher leakage.